# Are there any scenarios where browser will add inline CSS automatically?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, internet-explorer, css

I see this behaviour in IE 8. Here when the grid view is rendered, the `<td>` element automatically comes with "white-space:nowrap" . This doesnt happen in IE 6.

Are there any such scenarios where such styles are added by IE automatically ?

Comment: Does it appears in other version of IE too? IE9? Maybe it's some user-agent-conditionnal code in the grid view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you haven't done a css-reset? http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/